# require() in user's default browser from electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

I'm trying to make an electron app that has a discord authorization. The prompt for the auth is from the user's default browser so user can easily just press authorize rather than logging in from the electron app. I use **express** so discord can redirect the authorization to the **localhost**.

Problem is that I need to send the information from the localhost to the react app by using ipcRenderer which uses `require('electron')` but since it's the **renderer** process you cant use it.

How would I go about this problem?

Comment: No, you can't use IPC because it's a whole different application than Electron, not just because it's in the renderer. Have you checked [custom-URL links for your Electron application](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app) that you could supply to Discord as the callback URL?

Comment: thank you kind sir on the internet, I did not know that cheers!